# MonoDevelop: Resetting the C# code formatting

Tags: monodevelop

Some how my projects (many) are formatting strangely when I ask for a code cleanup (CTRL+SHIFT+F)

Is there a way to clear all the project prefs, establish a global one, and that apply everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting policies are not global, they are per solution. The global preferences are only used for new solutions or solutions that somehow do not have a formatting policy (e.g. created by Visual Studio).

If you want, you can use the "Custom Policies" dialog to create a new named policy set, and apply that to existing solutions.